# Which directory has more files and which has more subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a shell script that compares the sizes of two directories
X and Y, and reports which directory has more files and which directory has more subdirectories. So X and Y are two arguments.

I know the code for counting files in a directory is

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

I was having some trouble with the arguments and comparisons.

Also the same thing for subdirectories. I am new to shell scripting so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post any code that you've written or errors that you've received? As written your question is very broad.

Comment: `find $dir1 -type d | wc -l` should give you a count of directories, including `$dir1` itself. `find $dir1 -type f | wc -l` will count regular files (not symlinks, devices, or whatever else). If you want disk space used by a directory, do `du -s $dir1`. Replace `$dir1` with whatever path you want.

Comment: `ls -l | wc -l` does not count files. It counts the lines of output produced by `ls`, some of which are probably files, some of which might be directories, and at least one of which is usally a header of some sort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For files you can do:

```
filesX=$(find "${X}" -type f | wc -l)
filesY=$(find "${Y}" -type f | wc -l)

if (( filesX < filesY )); then
    echo "${Y} has more files"
elif (( filesX > filesY )); then
    echo "${X} has more files"
else
    echo "${X} and ${Y} have same number of files"
fi
```

For dirs it's basically the same:

```
dirsX=$(find "${X}" -type d | wc -l)
dirsY=$(find "${Y}" -type d | wc -l)

if (( dirsX < dirsY )); then
    echo "${Y} has more dirs"
elif (( dirsX > dirsY )); then
    echo "${X} has more dirs"
else
    echo "${X} and ${Y} have same number of dirs"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Man! your code really helped1 Appreciate it a lot!